# Undefined references with latest SDL 2.0 build

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

I've been using an old version of SDL2 for a while now, and never had any problems; but now it looks like things aren't linking properly, and I have no idea why.

Here's the entire program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
    SDL_CreateWindow("test", 100, 100, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using codeblocks+mingw32, and here's what I imagine is the relevant part of the build log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LE:\...\SDL2-2.0.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LE:\Programs\Code-Blocks\lib  -o bin\Debug\SDL2test.exe obj\Debug\main.o -pg -lgmon  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2.dll -lgdi32 -lwinmm -luser32
```

And here are the errors:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

For the sake of comparison, here's the build log for a program that compiles fine using an SDL2 build from a few months back:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LE:\...\SDL2\lib -LE:\Programs\Code-Blocks\lib  -o bin\Debug\SDL2.exe obj\Debug\main.o -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -pg -lgmon  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll -lSDL2 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -luser32
```

Comment: Try building with the `-shared` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your linker options look good.

Make sure that you have codeblocks looking at the right directories.

i686-w64-mingw32 is for 32-bit compilation.

x86_64-w64-mingw32 is for 64-bit compilation.

I had the same problem you did and it took me a long time to figure out that my initial assumption was incorrect.

use the following directories for 32-bit compilation:

Search Directories:

Compiler

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\

C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2_ttf-2.0.12\i686-w64-mingw32\include\

C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2_image-2.0.0\i686-w64-mingw32\include\
```

Linker

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2_ttf-2.0.12\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

C:\Users\USERNAME\Programs\SDL\SDL2_image-2.0.0\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
```

I hope this helps!

Jensen